# To view uploaded files in django

Tags: django-models

I have an fileupload filed in my models, I can upload documents and save it. While I am trying to view the same document via django modles I receive page not found error. Is there anything want to do to view the documents.

Answer (score 1):

Some code of models.py and admin.py would be helpfull. That error page is from django or it is standard error page? are you in DEBUG=True mode?